# MongoDB - DB Reference returns null value

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, dbref

[image: output]

As seen in this image when I try to retrieve address details from collection 'address_home' using DB Reference in MongoDB, it returns null value. Anybody know what is the problem with this code?

I tried the code in the image. I want it to print data from the 'address_home' collection in place of the 'DBRef()' data on users table.

```
use tutorialspoint

db.address_home.insertOne({ "_id": ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"), "building": "22 A, Indiana Apt", "pincode": 123456, "city": "Los Angeles", "state": "California" })

db.users.insertOne( { "_id": ObjectId("53402597d852426020000002"), "address": { "$ref": "address_home", "$id": ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"), "$db": "tutorialspoint" }, "contact": "987654321", "dob": "01-01-1991", "name": "Tom Benzamin" })

var user = db.users.findOne({"name":"Tom Benzamin"})
var dbRef = user.address
```

and finally,

```
db[dbRef.$ref].findOne({"_id":(dbRef.$id)})
```

but, this command returns null as seen in the image.

I tried this code from here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_database_references.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Data Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/#data-types) documentation:

> Compared to the legacy mongo shell, MongoDB Shell(`mongosh`) has type handling which is better aligned with the default types used by the MongoDB drivers.

For example, the constructor's signature of [5.6/classes/BSON.DBRef.html#constructor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/classes/BSON.DBRef.html#constructor) class in node-mongodb-driver:

```
new DBRef(collection: string, oid: ObjectId, db?: string, fields?: Document): DBRef
```

Properties:

| name | type | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| collection | string | the collection name. |
| oid | [ObjectId](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/classes/BSON.ObjectId.html) | the reference ObjectId. |
| db | string | optional db name, if omitted the reference is local to the current db. |

The `user.address` is an instance of `DBRef` class:

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> user.address instanceof DBRef
true
```

So the command in `mongosh` should be:

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> db[user.address.collection].findOne({_id: user.address.oid})
{
  _id: ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"),
  building: '22 A, Indiana Apt',
  pincode: 123456,
  city: 'Los Angeles',
  state: 'California'
}
```

Or, use [toJSON()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/classes/BSON.DBRef.html#toJSON) method to get the [BSON.DBRefLike](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/interfaces/BSON.DBRefLike.html) data.

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> dbRef.toJSON()
{
  '$ref': 'address_home',
  '$id': ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"),
  '$db': 'test'
}
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> db[dbRef.toJSON().$ref].findOne({_id: dbRef.toJSON().$id})
{
  _id: ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"),
  building: '22 A, Indiana Apt',
  pincode: 123456,
  city: 'Los Angeles',
  state: 'California'
}
```

The user document(*Note: I use `test` database, not `tutorialspoint`*):

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> db.users.findOne({name: 'Tom Benzamin'})
{
  _id: ObjectId("53402597d852426020000002"),
  address: DBRef("address_home", ObjectId("534009e4d852427820000002"), "test"),
  contact: '987654321',
  dob: '01-01-1991',
  name: 'Tom Benzamin'
}
```

`mongosh` version:

```
$ mongosh --version
1.10.1
```

MongoDB version:

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> db.version()
6.0.6
```

P.S. There is not even MongoDB and `mongosh` version information in tutorialspoint site's documentation. I guess I won't use it.